# Advice on creating a local instance of Azure Website

Tags: visual-studio, azure-web-app-service, umbraco7

I have, I admit, done things the wrong way round and created an Umbraco installation on Azure, developed multiple websites on that installation and only just decided I want a local instance for further development purposes.

Given that that's where I am, does anyone have any advice for how to go about achieving this? I have tried installing Visual Studio Community 2017 and MS SQL Server 2017 Developer and while I can connect to Azure with Visual Studio I don't seem to be able to work out how to view the installation, much less copy it down to my PC (something which I my searches seem to suggest isn't possible with Visual Studio).

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to copy down the site via FTP and the database using SQL Server Management Tools (assuming you are using SQL Server and not SQL CE).

You can get the FTP connection information from the Azure portal.  The web root is in /site/wwwroot.  Copy it down locally and you will be able to open it in Visual Studio as a Web Site.   For the database, you can connect to the Azure SQL database with SQL Server Management Tools  (you should have the connection info from when you created the database) and then right click on the database, select "Tasks" > "Export Data-tier application..." which will allow you to save a 'bacpac' file your local machine.  You can then connect to your local SQL Server instance, and then right click on the "Databases" node in the Object Explorer and select "Import Data-tier application..."   Once the database is imported, you may need to create/update a SQL Server user and grant it access to the database you just imported. For local development I just set the user to be owner of the the db.   Back in Visual Studio, you should update the "umbracoDbDSN" connection string to use the new local database.  At this point you should be able to run the website locally.

Comment: I figured some of this out myself in between asking the question and your answer, so I downloaded the site through ftp and got the sql server .bacpac and installed that. I have the website as a solution in Visual Studio and am connected to the database according to the server explorer. However when I try to open the url listed in the website properties I get 'This site can't be reached. localhost refused to connect.'

Comment: Sorry it took so long to reply, I'm only in once a week